# Why doesn't my code print the whole list?

Tags: python

here is my code:

```
import string
l=string.ascii_lowercase

the_input=list(raw_input("Enter your message to encode it: "))
for i in the_input:
    xyz=[l.find(i)+1] 
#set_alpha_num=[alphabets.index(find) for find in user_msg] 
print(xyz)
```

If I enter `"test"` then it prints just `[20]` but I need the output should be like: `[20, 5, 19, 20]`

Comment: And don't you want to append to the list instead of overwriting it?

Comment: `xyz` is being overwritten on every iteration you want to append to it

Comment: @EdChum how can I do that?

Comment: `[l.find(i)+1]` creates a list with one element in it, an integer between `1` and `26`. Are you sure that that is what you want `xyz` to be set to? It also creates a *new list object* for each iteration of the `for i in the_input:` loop, replacing the previous value for `xyz` each time.

Comment: declare `xyz=[]` outside of your `for` loop and append like this `xyz.append(l.find(i)+1)` inside your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as you asked:

```
import string
l=string.ascii_lowercase
xyz=[]
the_input=list(raw_input("Enter your message to encode it: "))
for i in the_input:
    xyz +=[l.find(i)+1]
#set_alpha_num=[alphabets.index(find) for find in user_msg]
print(xyz)
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep reassigning `xyz`, so it will be whatever you last assigned to it.

Since you have one list that you want to transform into a different list, I'd use a list comprehension here:

```
[l.find(i)+1 for i in the_input]
#   ^ Whatever's here is appended to a new list
```

Comment: In l.find(i) why doesn't it say that i is used before assignment?

Comment: @HaileyWilliams That's how list comprehensions work. The variables are made available on the right, and used on the left (at least in simple cases like this).

Answer (score 0):

you may save all the results in each loop using a list (Out):

```
import string
l=string.ascii_lowercase
out = []
the_input=list(input("Enter your message to encode it: "))
for i in the_input:
    xyz=[l.find(i)+1] 
    out.append(xyz)
#set_alpha_num=[alphabets.index(find) for find in user_msg] 
print(out)
```

OutPut for "test":

```
[20, 5, 19, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
l=string.ascii_lowercase

the_input=list(input("Enter your message to encode it: "))
list1 = list()
for i in the_input:
   t = l.find(i)+1
   list1.append(t) 
#set_alpha_num=[alphabets.index(find) for find in user_msg] 
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
[20, 5, 19, 20]
```

Explanation:

Create a empty list `list1` and append the values to it to get the required output

From your code:

As you are assigning the values to `xyz` it is getting updated in each iteration of `for` loop. so you got only `[20]` for `t` character